# In Windows, how to force C's fread to return even if there's no pending input?

Tags: c, winapi, stdin, eof, fread

In a Windows program with two threads: `thread1` and `thread2`.

When `thread1` is blocked in the call `fread(buffer, 1, 10, stdin)` waiting for input, is it possible to do something from `thread2` to force `fread` to return?

So far I tried calling `fclose(stdin)` from `thread2`, but it doesn't seem to work. The program gets stuck at the `fclose` call until some input is avaible in the `stdin` stream.

What I'm trying to achieve is to terminate `thread1` gracefully instead of just killing it with `TerminateThread`, because there's some work that `thread1` has to do at the end.

Another thing to consider is that `stdin` is one end of a named pipe. I don't have control over the program at the other end of the pipe.
What I need is just to disconnect my program from its end of the pipe (`stdin` in this case).

Comment: does it need to be fread or could you maybe use IOCP with something like `ReadFile` with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and use `CancelIoEx` to cancel the requested read? Otherwise just give [`CancelSynchronousIo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/FileIO/cancelsynchronousio-func) a shot.

Comment: It's not possible in Standard C. To do this functionality you could use the operating system's I/O API instead

Comment: Yes, closing the stream is what it takes.  But any standard C library implementation today had to be made thread-safe, so fclose() is going to deadlock.  You need to use the backdoor, CancelIo() or CloseHandle().   Your CRT should also have a backdoor to obtain the HANDLE you need.

Comment: @PeterT, thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. I can't use `CancelSynchronousIo` specifically because I need to support WinXP as well, but I found the solution for that [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/284348b6-65b7-4a63-be75-18c18832fdc0/cancelioex-under-win-2k-win-xp-using-vc?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: @Getfree: If you have time, writing that as a self-answer with a description of how you solved the problem would be a great way to contribute to stack overflow. This is certainly a problem others could want to know the answer to.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `fclose(stdin)` is a very bad idea; it causes undefined behavior if it happens before the `fread` (which it's not ordered with respect to) or if the thread calling `fread` does **anything** else with `stdin` after `fread` returns, and it does not unblock the `fread` since `fclose` cannot proceed until it obtains a lock on `stdin`, which the in-progress `fread` is excluding.

`stdio` is just fundamentally unsuitable for what you want to do here. You could patch it up via forwarding through a second pipe, with yet another thread reading from `stdin` and writing into your new pipe. Then you could abort an `fread` on the read end of your pipe by closing the write end of it. The extra thread would still be stuck, but that doesn't really matter if you're going to be terminating anyway. Alternatively (and this is probably cleaner) you would use file descriptors (or Windows file handles) instead of stdio and `poll` (or the Windows equivalent) to determine whether there's input to be read. You could combine these approaches to put the Windows-specific file handle logic in the extra thread (thus being able to terminate it cleanly) and continue to use portable `stdio` in your program logic thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `CancelSynchronousIo` you can close the underlying file handle with `CloseHandle`, like this:

```
CloseHandle((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stdin))) ;
```

That should cause `fread` to return.